# How to add new font in PhpPresentation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phppresentation

I am trying to make a presentation from Laravel using the PhpPresentation library.

I want to change the font of the presentation from default to "Century Gothic".

Using `->setName($pValue = 'Century Gothic');` is not working.

Comment: I simply changed that inside `/Style/Font.php`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for defining the default font in a presentation.

I created an issue : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/issues/237

The only way for the moment is : define the font in Century Gothic for each shape.

Comment: Hi @Progi1984  I tried that also for each shape but I think that font is not supported by PHPPresentation...

Comment: Thanks @Progi, actually font was not installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

See my example:

```
$shape = $currentSlide->createRichTextShape()
    ->setHeight(50)
    ->setWidth(200)
    ->setOffsetX(760)
    ->setOffsetY(235);
$textRun = $shape->createTextRun($texto201);
$textRun->getFont()->setBold(false)
    ->setItalic(true)
    ->setSize(24)
    ->setName('Trebuchet MS')
```

Use `->setName('Trebuchet MS')` to change.

@Progi1984

in PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Font
you can change the __construc() method
$this->name = 'Calibri';

So always that you instanced new font is default